# How do i get first and last year of this decade in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How do i get first and last year of this decade ?
Can someone pls help me regarding this?

I can get 1st last date of this year, but what about this decade? here is my code

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
        NSString *theDateFormatted = [dateFormat stringFromDate: Sdate];

        theDateFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", theDateFormatted, @"-01-01 12:00:00 AM"];

        // set last of month
        NSString *theDateFormattedE = [dateFormat stringFromDate: Sdate];
        theDateFormattedE = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", theDateFormattedE, @"-12-31 11:59:59 PM"];

        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
        Edate = [dateFormat dateFromString:theDateFormattedE];
        Sdate = [dateFormat dateFromString:theDateFormatted];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB Status" message: theDateFormattedE delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
```

Comment: Well, first define "decade" -- some folks count from x0, others from x1.  Next, can't you just figure that out -- if you have year 1978 then substitute a zero (or one) for the "8", then add nine for the last year of the same decade.

Comment: well.thats a nice idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the current year from the date, like so :

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar     components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate]; // Get necessary date components

NSInteger year = [components year];
```

Then, to get the start year of the decade,

```
NSInteger firstYearOfTheDecade = year - (year % 10); //Add 1 to this if you want to start from x1
```

and for the last year

```
NSInteger lastYearOfTheDecade = firstYearOfTheDecade + 9;
```